# Launch Image in asset catalog only has spaces for 2x and R4

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios7.1, xcode5.1

I'm starting the design phase of an app and this is the first app I've ever built. The app is currently using iOS SDK 7.1 and has a Deployment Target of 7.0

Even after all of the research I have done so far here on stackoverflow and reading the iOS 7 design guidelines, I am still having trouble figuring this out.

When I go to my asset catalog, and click on LaunchImage, it only has two slots. One for 2x and one for R4. However, a lot of the screenshots I keep seeing online have more slots than that.

If I click on the `+` symbol and select New Launch Image, then this new LaunchImage has a ton of slots for iPhone and iPad, even for iOS 5, 6, and 7.

Am I correct in thinking that I am only supposed to use the default LaunchImage with slots for 2x and R4, because my app has a deployment target of iOS 7.0 and the only iPhone models that iOS 7 supports have retina displays?

EDIT: AppIcon in the asset catalog is similar. It only has 3 slots, and all of them have 2x underneath them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **AppIcon** and **LaunchImage** assets in asset catalog respond to your project configuration.

1. If you have iOS SDK 7.1 and deployment target of 7.0, **you do not need any iOS 6 resources**, because your project will not run on iOS 6 operating system. Why would you waste application size, when resources are not used ever?
2. Same goes for iPhone and iPad. You probably selected your project as iPhone only, so **you do not need iPad** resources.
3. If you selected deployment target 7.0, that means that the device needs at least iOS 7.0 installed for your application to run. Because iOS 7 only runs on Retina phones (iPhone 4 and newer), **you do not need resources for anything else except Retina** (which have the @2x in the name).

   *You do need resources for normal devices, if you are running on the iPad, because iPad 2 and iPad Mini do not have Retina.*

Hope this explains it.

Comment: One other question though, I actually forgot to add "@2x" before the .png in my images. So I created 2 images, 640 x 1136 and 640 x 960, and I added them in the 2 slots, and I'm not getting any errors and the app is running fine. Are you not required to add "@2x" to retina images if the app is only going to use retina images anyways?

Comment: With asset catalogs, you specify manually which is Retina image and the OS will use that one. So it is not required, but for iOS 6, you should have @2x with it.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, because I am only using iOS 7 I am not required to use "@2x" in the image file name because all the app supports are retina devices anyways? But if I wanted to support devices without retina displays, then I would be required to add the "@2x" to the retina image file names?

Comment: As long as you are using an Asset Catalog, you will be fine. Xcode manages this for you. But yes, this is how images were loaded in previous iOS versions. Read more here: https://www.iphonelife.com/blog/31369/unleash-your-inner-app-developer-managing-images-xcode-5-asset-catalogs